# docker-engine installs makes wifi undetected

Tags: networking, wireless, docker

I am on a fresh 16.10 install, and trying to install Docker on it.
I added the PPA, updated apt, and launched:

```
sudo apt install docker-engine
```

It works perfectly.

Now, when I reboot, my Wifi is not detected! It seems docker interface creates a conflict with my existing network interface. It is even removing it from ifconfig.

Edit: here are some commands output before/after:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

(same before and after)

`$ ifconfig -a`

Before:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 62183  bytes 3862625 (3.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62183  bytes 3862625 (3.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp58s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.0.18  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
            inet6 fe80::46f0:8dad:aded:afbf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 9c:b6:d0:d4:83:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 74434  bytes 83729393 (83.7 MB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 56425  bytes 9260378 (9.2 MB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

After:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:48:c6:4c:bb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 3059  bytes 199733 (199.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3059  bytes 199733 (199.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`

Before:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

After:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

`ip a`

Before:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp58s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:b6:d0:d4:83:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.18/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp58s0
       valid_lft 863729sec preferred_lft 863729sec
    inet6 fe80::46f0:8dad:aded:afbf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

After:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:48:c6:4c:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ifconfig -a` (just after having docker-engine installed, before reboot):

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:bc:88:15:f6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 70992  bytes 4402758 (4.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 70992  bytes 4402758 (4.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp58s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.18  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::46f0:8dad:aded:afbf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:d4:83:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 93928  bytes 110058973 (110.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68156  bytes 10649275 (10.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The following command is not doing anything either:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

I am working on a laptop which has no ethernet connection, only Wifi.

The PPA added in sources.list is:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

Comment: What does your /etc/network/interfaces file look like before and after the install? What does the full 'ifconfig -a' report before and after? What does the output of 'ip a' return? What does your /proc/cmdline look like? Anything unusual in there that might change how the interfaces are handled (such as net.ifnames or biosdevnames)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe kinda off-topic but, which _ppa_ did you added? Official docker repos doesn't support _16.10_ by default...

Comment: I added the output of the commands. I still can't figure out what's going on... @dgonzalez: do you think it is related to the PPA I added?

Comment: I'm not sure (I even believe it should work ok), however this repo doesn't support 16.10, only 16.04. I'm using docker (from main repos) on my laptop & home server with no problem, I'll suggest avoid using ppa's execpt if you have special requeriments, so you can benefit from _Canonical team_ work.

Comment: I also tried to install through the apt way: sudo apt install docker.io The result is the same, no wifi at restart.

Comment: I had the same issue on 14.04. I use the proprietary driver. I disable it then re-enabled it and it works fine now.

Comment: 16.10 is end of life for a while now, do you have the same issues on 17.10 or 17.04 ?

Answer (score 5):

Research indicates that this is likely related to [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322) If so a workaround would be to modify `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to be

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker0
```

which will make NetworkManager ignore docker adapters.

Sources:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30343

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322