# How to confirm software or hardware cause, on wifi issue?

Tags: networking, 18.10, iwlwifi

For a few days, I'm having a strong wifi issue with my ASUS UX305FA (laptop), running Ubuntu 18.10.

I loose wifi connection with apparently no reason, and when I try to reconnect no network is detected...

As I installed **Docker** and noticed it in my `ifconfig -a` a *docker0* entry, I followed this post: [docker-engine installs makes wifi undetected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874226/docker-engine-installs-makes-wifi-undetected). But doesn't seem to work in my case (still *docker0*).

I also tried to make a hardware test, using the **Phoronix test suite**, but I'm not sure to understand the report it gives me :/

Is there anyone here with the same kind of issue? What could I do to fix it, or at least to confirm hardware or software problem?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Did wifi work well before installing docker?

Comment: Well, I couldn't be 100% sure (hard week...) but it seems that the problem started after installing Docker, yes :)

Comment: If possible try to uninstall docker and check whether the problem exists

Comment: Look at the logs with `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Logs are huge and I'm not sure of what I am looking for... Could you be more precise, @waltinator ?

Comment: I don't know if it will help to go further, but here is something I noticed in the logs: `NetworkManager[945]: <warn>  [1554899369.8599] dns-sd-resolved[0x559569251c20]: Failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 6 not known`... Any clue?

Comment: Hello again... Sorry to insist, but is there anyone who could help me? Thx in advance (I'm tired sharing my wifi connection through my smartphone... do I need to think about buying a new machine, or it is software related ?)